# How to print words that contain only letters?

Tags: linux, shell

If I'm given a file how can I print the words that contain only the characters A-Za-z (so only letters) in alphabetical order? Should I use awk?Could someone help me with suggestions/example?

If I have the file `file1.txt` and its content is:

```
ahk4 ble ach cop v59l k9l
h6j alo
```

The output will look like this:

```
ach alo ble cop
```

Comment: Providing example input and output, as well as your current best attempt at solving the problem, would make the question more answerable and more useful for future visitors. My guess is that `grep` may be handy for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the words contain alphabet only:

```
$ tr -cs '[:alnum:]' '[\n*]' <file | grep -E '^[[:alpha:]]+$'
ble
ach
cop
alo
```

To get your desired output:

```
$ tr -cs '[:alnum:]' '[\n*]' <file |
  grep -E '^[[:alpha:]]+$'         | 
  sort                             |
  paste -sd ' ' -
```